# z-index to hide paragraph behind other elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, stylesheet

I have a paragraph (`.about-info p`) that I am trying to hide behind another element (`.about-container`). I am trying to layer the elements so that `.about-info p` appears behind `.about-container` but have been unsuccessful so far using `z-index`.

Can you help me understand why? The [site is here](http://www.californiafootgolfclub.com/dev/about/). Thanks for your ideas!

```
<div class="about-info">
   <p>stuff</p>
</div>

<div class="about-container">
   More stuff
</div>

.about-container { z-index:9999; position:relative; }
.about-info { background-color: #d7d7d7; z-index:-700; position:relative; }
.about-info p { z-index: -800; position:relative;}
```

Comment: please can you put your code here too

Comment: Didn't need it to get the answer. But provided anyways for the sticklers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the body has background image and the `about-container` doesn't! thus it is transparent.
so if you put a background-image (same as body) to the `about-container` it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't posted your full code highlighting the problem, I'm going to assume you haven't added `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to `.about-info p` to make the z-index work.

Comment: Thanks but I did. I can copy and paste the code but it is online, providing the context as well

Comment: if you can post the css for the `.about-info p` and `.about-container` then that would help

Comment: Yeh other guy above looked at it for two seconds and had the answer. Sometimes link & firebug is really the easiest way to understand the problem. But thanks for the busy work